# Fazer envio para API via POST Request no Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, api, rest, delphi-10

Boa noite Galera, sou iniciante em Delphi e estou tentando enviar uma requisição de criação para uma Api mas estou com uma certa dificuldade com o POST. como faço esse envio? estou tentando por essa API: https://reqres.in
Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    res: TJSONValue;
    ParamNome: TRequestParam;
    ParamProfissao: TRequestParam;
    ParamArray: array of TRequestParam;
    ParamObj: TRequestParam;

begin

    ParamNome := RequestParam('name', 'Morpheus');
    ParamProfissao := RequestParam('job', 'Leader');
    ParamArray :=[
            ParamNome,
            ParamProfissao
            ];
    ParamObj := RequestParam('nome', ParamArray);

    res := TRestService.Ocorrencia.request(
        'https://reqres.in/api',
        'users',
       TRestService.POST


    );
    ParamObj := RequestParam('nome', ParamArray);
    Memo1.Lines.Text := ParamObj.valor.ToJSON;

end;
```

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar??

Comment: O que está a acontecer com esse código?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda não estava conseguindo copilar, mas consegui passando o valor ParamObj dentro do Array.
`TRestService.POST,   [ ParamObj  ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver passando o valor ParamObj dentro do array.

```
var
    res: TJSONValue;
    ParamNome: TRequestParam;
    ParamProfissao: TRequestParam;
    ParamArray: array of TRequestParam;
    ParamObj: TRequestParam;

begin

    ParamNome := RequestParam('name', 'Felipe');
    ParamProfissao := RequestParam('job', 'Cozinheiro');
    ParamArray :=[
            ParamNome,
            ParamProfissao
            ];
    ParamObj := RequestParam('usuario', ParamArray);

    res := TRestService.Ocorrencia.request(
            'https://reqres.in/api',
            'users',
            TRestService.POST,
            [
                ParamObj
            ]
    );

    Memo1.Lines.Text := res.ToJSON;
   
end;
```